# Why does my winform button.BackgroundImage value come out as System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently creating Minesweeper in c# using winform buttons as the tiles. I have a mouse event that checks when the right mouse button goes down (right click) to apply the 'flag' to the tile.

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var tile = (Button)sender;
        tile.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\MyFiles\flag.png");
        Console.WriteLine("BackgroundImage: "+tile.BackgroundImage);
    }
}
```

When running the game I can right click a tile and it will apply the flag.png image but the console messages out "BackgroundImage: System.Drawing.Bitmap". The plan is to check for what background image the tile clicked has so I can turn it back to a regular tile if I click it again like so:

```
if tile.BackgroundImage == Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\MyFiles\flag.png")
{
  tile.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\MyFiles\tile.png");
}
```

I have tried using the BackgroundImage.tag to apply an identifier to the button but that doesn't seem to get saved as it messages out blank. Why does the button not save BackgroundImage as the file path instead of 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' and is there a way I can check the button pressed has that image assigned to its background?

Comment: Button has a tag property - use that. Forms can load png images, but all images are converted to bitmaps internally.

Comment: See following for bitmap format so you can write your code using a bitmap : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am using the tag for something else currently

Comment: Don't use `Image.FromFile()` there. Add those images to the Project's Resources (so you don't need sparse files anymore). Then assign the images from the Resources to some Fields, when your Form is initialized (in its Constructor). Then you can also *compare the images* (you're actually comparing instances of objects, that that will do)

Comment: `tile.BackgroundImage.ToString()` (which is what Console.WriteLine calls) just returns the string representation of the type. That's not useful for an image.

Comment: Try using [Button.Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). The backgroundImage property is inherited from Control, and that is probably not what you want. Also note that it can be difficult to get winforms to look good without custom rendering. Using WPF might be a bit more flexible in that regard, but has a bit higher learning threshold.

Answer (score 0):

One possible remedy for **Why does my winform button.BackgroundImage value come out as System.Drawing.Bitmap** is to make sure the image can be located. What you're doing doesn't seem that far off the mark in terms of loading the image from file, but you might want to streamline the process with some suggestions:

[image: sample game board]

One straightforward way to ensure the files are located is to mark them to be copied to the output directory.

[image: Copy to output directory]

Then you can make a dictionary (or an `ImageList`) by loading from a location that is known by app at runtime.

```
enum SelectedImage{ None, Flag, Bomb, }

Dictionary<SelectedImage, Image> Images = new Dictionary<SelectedImage, Image>
{
    {  SelectedImage.None, null },
    {  SelectedImage.Flag, Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images", "flag.png")) },
    {  SelectedImage.Bomb, Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images", "bomb.png")) },
};
```

---

**Inherit Button**

It might make things easier if you make a custom button class that is aware of the `SelectedImage` enum and can fire an event when that property changes.

```
class MSButton : Button
{
    public SelectedImage SelectedImage
    {
        get => _selectedImage;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_selectedImage, value))
            {
                _selectedImage = value;
                SelectedImageChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    SelectedImage _selectedImage = 0;
    public event EventHandler SelectedImageChanged;

    // Cycle through the images
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        SelectedImage = (SelectedImage)(((int)SelectedImage + 1) % 3);
    }
}
```

**Game Board**

Now you can consume the custom button class using a `TableLayoutPanel` (with your chosen dimensions) for a gameboard.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    const float DIM = 40F;
    tableLayoutPanel.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
    tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 10;
    tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 10;
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, DIM));
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, DIM));
            var button = new MSButton
            {
                Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF, // All
                BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
            };
            button.SelectedImageChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if(sender is MSButton msbutton)
                {
                    msbutton.BackgroundImage = Images[msbutton.SelectedImage];
                }
            };
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button, col, row);
        }
    }
    // Size including 1 px borders.
    tableLayoutPanel.Width = (int)((DIM * 10) + 11);
    tableLayoutPanel.Height = (int)((DIM * 10) + 11);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the button not save BackgroundImage as the file path instead of 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

String concatenation simply calls the `ToString()` for non-string objects. `Bitmap` has no overridden `ToString()` that's why you just see the full name of its type in the console. But it couldn't return any filename anyway because it's simple not stored. A bitmap can be created without any file, eg. from a memory stream or simply by specifying a size and a pixel format.

> Is there a way I can check the button pressed has that image assigned to its background?

Actually there is a natively supported way of associating string names for predefined images:

1. Create an [`ImageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist) (you can do it at design time, you can find the `ImageList` in the toolbar). Do not forget to set the bit depth to 24 or 32 bpp.
2. Add the images to your image list. You can do it from the designer where you can set a `Name` for every image. If you do it programmatically you can do it like this: `imageList1.Images.Add("flag.png", Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\MyFiles\flag.png"));`
3. For your button(s) just set the [`ImageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.imagelist) property. You can do it at design time as well.

Now at run-time you can set the [`ImageKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.imagekey) property to set the image. You can also read this to determine which image is currently displayed.

```cs
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var tile = (Button)sender;
        tile.ImageKey = "flag.png";
        Console.WriteLine("Current image: " + tile.ImageKey);
    }
}
```

The other obvious benefit of this is that you don't need to load the image from file again and again.